# How to run node postgres inside Electron?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, electron

I'm trying to use postgres (pg) inside electron.
When the window opens, the connection and query works normally, but when the electron window is reloaded, pg connect and queries does not return anything.

```html
    <script>
    const { Client } = require('pg')

    async function query() {
      const client = new Client({
        host: '192.168.99.100',
        port: 5433,
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database',
      })
      console.log(await client.connect())

      const res = await client.query('SELECT * from users')
      console.log(res)
      await client.end()
    }

    query()
  </script>
```

PS: If i try to use Knex for connect and query the database, it returns this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
at Client_PG.acquireConnection
```

Comment: I noticed that, even when I go to other file via anchor tag, it does not work anymore...